# how to read a large file using readlines() or read(), cracking

Tags: python-2.7, loops, cracking

```
import mechanize
import cookielib 
def check():

            global browser
            global passwords
            try:
                    browser = mechanize.Browser()
                    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
                    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
                    browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
                    browser.set_handle_referer(True)
                    browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
                    browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
                    browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),max_time=1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    fwx=str(raw_input("\n[*] Exiting program .."))
                    sys.exit(1)

            try:
                    list = open(passwordlist, "r")
                    passwords = list.read()

                    while True:
                            k = 0
                            passwords = list.readlines()
                            if not passwords:
                                    break
                            while k < len(passwords):
                                    passwords[k] = passwords[k].strip()
                                    k += 1

                            search()
                            attack(password)
            except IOError:
                    fe=str(raw_input("\n [*] Error: check your passsword list path!! \n"))
                    sys.exit(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    fdd=str(raw_input("\n [*] Exiting program .."))
                    sys.exit(1)

            try:

                    search()
                    attack(password)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    fp=str(raw_input("\n [*] Exit program .."))
                    sys.exit(1)
```

im trying to read a long list in .lst assoc or lets say .csv list.
when i read() or readlines() the file in that loop nothing happen:

```
while True:                                
    k = 0
    passwords = list.readlines()
       if not passwords:
           break
       while k < len(passwords):
           passwords[k] = passwords[k].strip()
           k += 1

       search()
       attack(password)
```

i dont know what im not doing.. what will make the file striped and processed?
its working for a short list (less than 1gb) but it couldn't read all the contest for larger than that.

```
list = open(passwordlist, "r")
passwords = list.readlines()
k = 0
while k < len(passwords):
    passwords[k] = passwords[k].strip()
    k += 1
```

i want to read the full file.